# Rails how to create a DRY domain checker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating domain checker and are wondering what the best logic is.

I am using this rails gem: https://github.com/weppos/whois

My solution on have to create this:

I have 1 input field which the user type the domain name their want. And when it is submitted it renders all the available top domains.

In my action I would have:

```
@domain = params[:domain]
@dk = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.dk")
@com = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.com")
@it = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.it")
@no = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.no")
@se = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.se")
@is = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.is")

And 50 more domains ...
```

And then I would have a helper to apply a class to the instance variable dependent on it is available or not. Example named domain_check. So that I could write in the view <%= domain_check(@is) %>

Is there not a better solution to create a domain checker instead of creating about 50 repeated instance variables?

**UPDATE:**

```
module PublicHelper
require 'whois'
def domain_checker(obj, options={})
    options[:info]          ||= obj
    options[:info_class]    ||= 'info'
    options[:pinfo]         ||= obj
    options[:pinfo_class]   ||= 'pinfo'
if obj.available?
    content_tag(:span, options[:pinfo], :class => options[:pinfo_class])
    else
    content_tag(:span, options[:info], :class => options[:info_class])
    end
end
end
```

In view :

```
<% @results.each do |webhost| %>
<%= domain_checker(webhost) %><br />
  <% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Public#domain

Showing C:/Rails/webhostapp/app/views/public/domain.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `available?' for #<Array:0x23eb3f0>

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: ï»¿<% @results.each do |webhost| %>
2: <%= domain_checker(webhost) %><br />
3:   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

Controller:

```
country_codes = ['.dk', '.com', '.it', '.no'] # etc. could move this to a config if needed

@domain = params[:domain]

@results = {}
country_codes.each do |cc|
  @results[cc] = Whois.whois(@domain + cc).available?
end
```

Then @results is:

```
{".dk" => true, ".com" => false} # etc.
```

Then in the view (you can move it to a helper if desired):

```
<ul>
  <% @results.each_pair do |country_code, available| %>
    <% klass = available ? "pinfo" : "info" %>
    <li><%= @domain + country_code %><span class="<%= klass %>"></span></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have updated my question I have used your solution but have a problem with the helper

Comment: What is the final html output you expect?

Comment: I would expect this output: <span class="pinfo"></span> if true (available)  else <span class="info"></span> if not available

Comment: Where should the domain name appear?

Comment: A have no problem generating the domain name

Comment: That might be the case but it ties in closely with the question you're asking so in order for me to give you a full solution I need the code.

Comment: I shows the domain name like this in the loop: <%= @domain %><%= webhost[0] %> The spans I want to CSS  style with image or a check dependent on if they are available or not

Comment: What does .each_pair do? Does it just make 2 loops in one? Like webhost & webhost just named different ?

Comment: It always add the class pinfo to the span I have checked "google" and "sadasdfksdhfjod""

Comment: This did work, you may add it to your answer: http://pastie.org/2390911 How do I move the topdomains to my config application and how to make it a helper?

Comment: each_pair do |key, value|  iterates over a hash, key is the key of the hash (in your case the country code) and value is the value (in your case true or false)